# Find text and copy to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Log file which I have imported to Excel and I have filtered Col C based on a Criteria. Now I want to search through Col E for "TRUE". For every instance of "TRUE", I want to select the rows above it for Col D,E until I find an empty cell in Col E, copy those and paste it into a new worksheet in the same workbook.

[image]

As per the picture above, I want to copy Rows 9 to 1 in worksheet1 and Skip copying Rows 20 to 10 (Because Col E has FALSE) and copy rows 31 to 21 in worksheet2.

Comment: Good Day, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please could you paste your current code for what you want to do, this will help the users to look at where you can be assisted. Generally, this site is not for users to ask for someone to develop some code for them.

Comment: If you want help to develop a code for your idea. Then start with a `Loop` to run thought the columns and the `If` you find what you are looking for start another `Loop` to search up for the required text. Then assign that Range and copy it to the new sheet.

Comment: Do you mind sharing with us your first macro attempt, so we can help you to progress with it. BTW what your are trying to do can easily be done with a formula in column E, then AutoFilter and copy visible cells to the target sheet...

Comment: Thanks for the replies.. I am able to do it with google nd this forum's help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .areas

This is a tough one if you have no VBA experience and don't know what to look for. Here is a head start, based on the picture you have supplied I came up with this.

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim RangeArea As Range, c As Range

    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

    With sh
        For Each RangeArea In .Columns("E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Areas
            Set c = RangeArea.Find(what:="TRUE", lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                RangeArea.EntireRow.Copy
                Sheets.Add
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            Else
            End If
            .Select
        Next RangeArea
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
End Sub
```